# Values is redux store reverting to original state after switching view

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm having an issue in where by I switch routes, and the value of a property in my store is reverting back to it's original state. I'm using react 16 with react router v4.

I'm also noticing that the entire App component rerenders when I change routes. That seems over the top. It's running `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` every time. I'm noticing the `state` passed into `mapStateToProps` is always empty too.

I'm very puzzled.

main file

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
//install routing deps
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './store'

import App from './components/App';

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

store

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';


const defaultState = { count: 0 };

const enhancers = compose(
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f,
);

const store = createStore(rootReducer, defaultState, enhancers);

//adds hot reload for changes to reducer
if(module.hot){
    module.hot.accept('./reducers', ()=>{
        const nextRootReducer = require(`./reducers/index`).default;
        store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
};

export default store;
```

App component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../actions/actionCreators';

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <a href="/"> main</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href='/info'>info</a>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" render={() => <h1>kawaii world</h1>} />
                    <Route exact path="/info" render={() => <h1>v kawaii world ;)</h1>} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    };
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        count: state.count
    };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

Comment: in your **App** component instead of `a` tag use `Link` from `react-router-dom`

Comment: This was the absolute right answer thanks!

Comment: You're welcome buddy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make use of tag `a` literally you are saying that you are willing to go to another page but in react apps that's not the case. In react you navigate from one component to another.

So to fix your issue you need to do this:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to="/">Main</Link>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <Link to="/info">Info</Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <h1>kawaii world</h1>} />
          <Route exact path="/info" render={() => <h1>v kawaii world ;)</h1>} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```